# Can a unit test use more than one method of the class being tested?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, testing, junit5

Consider you implemented a `Stack` data structure and you are writing a test for the push and peek operations.

```
@Test
fun `push an element in the stack`() {
    stack.push("A")
    stack.push("B")
    assertEquals("B", stack.peek())
}

@Test
fun `peek from an non empty stack`() {
    stack.push("A")
    stack.push("B")
    stack.push("C")
    assertEquals("C", stack.peek())
}
```

The test for the `push` operation requires to also peek from the stack to make the assertion, and similarly the test for the `peek` operation requires to push into the stack to peek from.

Let's say for the push test case, if the test fails how one can know if the push method failed or the peek method.

So, is it a bad practice to use more than one method in a single unit test from the test class.

Comment: I think the conceptual problem is apparent in the naming of your tests. Both of your tests are actually testing the same behaviour: `peek on non-empty stack should return the last pushed element`. You can't (and shouldn't) have one test for `push` and one test for `peek`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it a bad practice to use more than one method in a single unit test from the test class

It is really NOT a bad practice. People too often believe that they should write unit tests for each method of the class, but that is really not the case.

Unit tests are here to test the behaviors of your class against expected behaviors. This may very well require several method calls for a proper setup and assertions.

Even in the simplest cases, it is quite common to use some method to setup some state, and then use another one to query the state. Your example is a very good one, you need to push some data, and then query it. Nothing wrong in that.

I think the conceptual problem in your current test design is apparent in the naming of your tests. Both of your tests are actually testing the same behaviour: `peek on non-empty stack should return the last pushed element`. You can't (and shouldn't) have one test for `push` and one test for `peek`. Instead, you can only test how they interact with each other.

Conversely, a single method can be used in many unit tests, to test different cases (in particular, edge cases). So it's also ok to use `push` and `peek` in multiple unit tests.

> if the test fails how one can know if the push method failed or the peek method

The test failure is not supposed to tell you which exact piece of code is broken, it's supposed to tell you what behavior doesn't respect the specifications (anymore). It's the developer's job to investigate where the bug is (if it's not obvious). Usually if you have nice focused tests (which doesn't mean single-method tests), it's really not that hard to find where things went wrong. If you struggle, you can use a debugger to help you check intermediate states at different points in time.

Comment: So, is it ok if you write a test case to check the behavior of one operation, which can fail due to an unwanted behavior of a completely another operation? Note that the subject for which the test case is written for is working completely fine.

Comment: The subject for which you write the test case is the `Stack` class. If the test fails, the stack implementation is broken. You are testing the behavior `peek on non-empty stack should return the last pushed element` - you're not testing `push` nor `peek` independently. This test could fail if there is a bug in `push`, or in `peek`, or in *any* piece of code involved in this operation (maybe it's a bug in the internal representation of the stack, or in a private helper method). More generally you want to test how `push` and `peek` interact, not one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. There is no way to independently test for both peek and push. They are two different operations for the same behavior. It makes sense to say that if the peek is working, then the push must be working fine.

Comment: *if the peek is working, then the push must be working fine* - it's not exactly what I meant, but you can view it this way: considering black box testing (assuming you don't observe the internal state of the class), you cannot even *define* what it means for `push` to "work" purely in terms of the class's API. You can only define what it means for the sequences of `push`+`peek` or `push`+`pop` to work (the returned item should be the one that you pushed). That's what unit tests are about: defining the smallest observable (and testable) behaviors of the class, which act as specifications.